# Send out base64 string to html5 player "media resource could not be decoded"

Tags: django, html, video-streaming, base64, gridfs

I have the uploaded video as a base64 string stored in GridFS and I have a django view that can put all the chunks together.

```
def serveVideo(request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = ''
    m = Multimedia.objects.get(id = args[0])
    chunks = client.db.fs.chunks.find({"files_id":ObjectId(m.media.grid_id)})
    for chunk in chunks:
        data = data + chunk['data']
    response = HttpResponse("data:video/webm;base64,"+data.split(",")[1], content_type='video/webm')
    return response
```

So on my client side I have this:

```
<video width="500" height="500" controls>
<source src="/videos/{{ post.video }}/" type="video/webm">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

But this doesn't seem to work, I'm getting an error in web console "Media resource could not be decoded".

**Note:** When I directly feed the base64 string into the src attribute it works fine.( so there is no problem with the base64 data of the video ).